# How to retrieve ambari cluster HDFS DISK USAGE METRICS

Tags: rest, metrics, ambari

I am trying to retrieve ambari UI metrics, if any one knows please reply.

For example if I call bellow Rest API I get ambari metrics in JSON:

```
http://<ambari-server>:8080/api/v1/clusters/<cluster-name>?fields=metrics/<metrics-name>[1430844925,1430848525,15]&_=1430848532904
```

where Metrics Name can be : cpu , network, memory , load ..

- cpu : To see cpu utilization of cluster
- network : to see network utilization of cluster
- memory : to see memory utilization of cluster
- load : to see load utilization of cluster

For example :

```
http://<ambari-server>:8080/api/v1/clusters/<cluster-name>?fields=metrics/network[1430844925,1430848525,15]&_=1430848532904
```

If I call above Rest API I will get network usage data in JSON.

Same as above I want how to retrieve `HDFS  DISK USAGE METRICS DATA`, if anyone knows, please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

For used capacity it's:

> http://:8080/api/v1/clusters//hosts//host_components/NAMENODE?fields=metrics/dfs/FSNamesystem/CapacityUsed

All available metrics you can check  by

> http://:8080/api/v1/clusters//hosts//host_components/NAMENODE?fields=metrics in metrics section

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

for HDFS disk available and HDFS disk usage over a period of time, you can use the below time series API while adjusting the timestamp according to your requirement.

**for HDFS Disk available:**

```
http://<ambari-server-name>:6188/ws/v1/timeline/metrics?metricNames=dfs.FSNamesystem.CapacityRemaining&appId=namenode&startTime=1629721493597&endTime=1630405297000'
```

**For HDFS Storage used:**

```
http://<ambari-server-name>:6188/ws/v1/timeline/metrics?metricNames=dfs.FSNamesystem.CapacityUsed&appId=namenode&startTime=1629721493597&endTime=1630405297000'
```